# Best way to configure AsyncTask for use in autocomplete search

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask

I am calling an AsyncTask in the onQueryTextChange method of a SearchView and displaying  the results in a list. The searching works, but occasionally tends to hang for a second if the user types quickly in the searchview. I want to further optimize this approach. Since its an autocomplete Search, as the user starting typing, several AsyncTasks gets queued for execution. But I am only interested in the very last searchrequest.

Currently, I am doing something like this

```
if (myAsyncTask != null)
    myAsyncTask.cancel(true);

   myAsyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(context,URL);
```

Is there a better way to do this? I would like to do something like this, if possible

```
myAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(new OptimizedExectionerService);
```

The OptimizedExectionerService class should cancel all pending and runnning tasks in the pool and ONLY process the last request that was made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a handler with a reasonable delay (to handle typing into an edittext).

```
private static final int SEARCH_DELAY = 500;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private SearchRunnable executeSearch = new SearchRunnable();

private queueSearch(String term) {
    // Remove any previous searches
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(executeSearch);

    // Set the search term for the runnable
    executeSearch.setSearchTerm(term);

    // Schedule the search in half a second
    mHandler.postDelayed(executeSearch, SEARCH_DELAY);
}

private class SearchRunnable implements Runnable {
    String searchTerm = null;

    public void setSearchTerm(String term) {
        searchTerm = term;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
         //Execute Search here
         new MyAsyncTask(context, searchTerm);
    }
};
```

Comment: This doesn't work well after testing. Remove callbacks only works for pending messages

Comment: The postDelayed should make the executeSearch wait for half a second (SEARCH_DELAY) before executing (meaning it's pending for those 500ms).  If the user is typing more than 1 character every 500ms, the old pending searches will be removed before they get executed in the asyncTask and only the last search after the user finishes typing will actually execute.  You can play with the search delay to tweak how well the cancelling mechanism works.  You can either call queueSearch from onQueryTextChange or just put the queueSearch code in there.

Comment: Also if the MyAsyncTask processing is taking a long time to execute / update, (like if you finish typing for a second and then start typing again), when the MyAsyncTask finishes (onPostExecute) you can check whether the search term (that you just did the autocomplete search on) matches the current search term and if not throw away the results (don't parse them or update the UI).

Comment: Upon double checking, I was creating a new instance of Handler and SearchRunnable every time the query is made, which is incorrect. Your code works perfectly! Thanks for the help!